# How to write this subselect sql into jpql?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, jpql

How do I transform the below sql into jpql? I'm just trying to count the number of rows returned by sub select.

```
select count(*) from (select t.prop1 from table1 t where t.someprop ='123' group by t.num);
```

I've tried

```
@Query("Select count(*) from (select t.prop1 from table1 t where t.someprop ='123' group by t.num")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's semantically appropriate. JPQL and SQL are not interchangeable, they serve different purpose as to JPA and JDBC. The idea of JPA is you get most of the relational db to object mapping done for you.

I think the appropriate action in your scenario is to autowire both EntityManager and JdbcOperations into your repository classes and use whichever serve the purpose (becareful with transaction though)

You can also use EntityManager.createNativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code.

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(t.prop1) FROM table1 t WHERE t.someprop ='123' GROUP BY t.num";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
long count = (long)query.getSingleResult();
```

If this query is used frequently, try NamedQuery & also set parameter for `someprop`, don't give value directly in the query, unless its constant.